# Check DLL OS version

Tags: dll

I mean for which platform, the particular DLL can be used. For example abc.dll can be used in 64 bit platform or 32 bit platform? How can I know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the source-code for the dll's project file, you can go to the project->properties and find out the targeted platform (x86/x64).
However, please note that by default all .NET assemblies are set to target "any" platform. So, the particular dll you are referring to could be a generic one, and could be used on both type of platforms.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The problem is I have 3rd party dll, no source code. I am using it in a project. And that project is in 32 bit platform. It was working all well but I have a requirement to play with the windows processes. And this creates problem on a 64 bit OS. I have downloaded another dll with 64 bit platform but It doesn't work with 64 bit OS. So was curious to know if we can check the platform version of DLL.